# Invert plot to obtain plot of a trascendental equation

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a transcendental equation of the form

$v(1-v^2)^{\sigma-1}=\frac{1}{u^2}$

I am looking for a solution of $v(u)$ but, as it can be seen, there are no analytical solutions. Nevertheless, I am able to see the the behavior of $v(u)$ if I solve for $u$ as $u= \sqrt{v^{-1}(1-v^2)^{1-\sigma}}$ and plot it with the axis "*inverted*". I can do this easily with python by using "plt.plot(Solution(y,$\sigma$), y)", where Solution(y,$\sigma$) is the function $u(v)$ and y is a simple numpy array. I say the axis are *inverted* since the usual plotting is done as "plt.plot(x,Solution(x))". This, for three values of $\sigma$ yields the plot:

[image]

As it can be seen from the original equation, the solution I'm looking for depends on the parameter $\sigma$. Hence, I want to translate this way of plotting to Mathematica so I am able to use the function `Manipulate[]` to explore, easily, different values of this parameter and obtain the different behaviors of $v(u)$. By using the code

`Plot[Sqrt[v^-1 (1 - v^2)^(1 - 3/4)], {v, 0, 1.5}, AxesLabel -> {"v", "u"}]`

I get the plot:

[image]

which is flipped. By using the function `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}`, i get:

[image]

So I'm looking for a way of this looking as the first plot.

Thanks!

Comment: By using "ContourPlot" you can directly draw v[u].

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@
  Table[v (1 - v^2)^(σ - 1) == 1/u^2,
   {σ, 1/4, 3/4, 1/4}],
 {u, 0, 4}, {v, 0, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 4,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   (StringForm["σ\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", #] & /@
     Range[1/4, 3/4, 1/4]),
   {.85, .835}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[(1 - v)^(1 - s)/v], v}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"u", "v"}, AspectRatio -> 0.7], {s, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: +1 With a few bells and whistles: `Manipulate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ {Sqrt[(1 - v)^(1 - #)/v], v} & /@ {0, s, 1}], {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.5], Dashed], Automatic}, AxesLabel -> {"u", "v"}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], {{s, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`